# lightning tree grid not removing data on filter change

Tags: lightning-web-components, json, wrapper-class, lightningtreegrid

I have a lightning-tree-grid with a filter. When I initially select a value in the filter, it works fine. However, when I change the filter to a new value, the previously pulled records remain in the list. I get the error -

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at HTMLTableSectionElement.removeChild"

I also want to note that this lwc works perfectly in the test environment. I'm only running into this issue in production.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Internal_Requirement__c">
  <lightning-input-field name="division" field-name="Division__c" onchange={handleValueChange4} value={division}> </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
<lightning-tree-grid
   columns={gridColumns}
   data={treeItems}
   is-loading={isLoading}
   key-field="Name"
   hide-checkbox-column = true
></lightning-tree-grid>
```

JS

```
@wire(getReqs, {division:'$division'})
    wiredReqs(value){
        console.log(value);
        this.wiredActivities = value;
        const { data, error } = value;
        if (data) {
            var tempjson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).split('items').join('_children'));
            this.treeItems = tempjson;
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
handleValueChange4(event) {
    this.division = event.target.value; 
}
```